# Writing at different locations in a file: Python

Tags: python, dictionary, file-handling, read-write

I have a dictionary of lists and I want to write the contents of the list to different locations in a file. So far what I have tried only works for the first two instance,i.e, the first two elements of the dictionary(I think it works for two elements because I tried to write it into a different file once the first instance was written). I cant get it to loop and write at multiple locations.

For eg:
The dict is `{'1':[a, b, c], '2': [c,d,e], '3': [g,h,i]}`

The contents of the file are :

```
Test 1  
some content  
some more content  

Test 2  
some other content  
some more content

Test 3....and so on.
```

I want my output to be:

```
Test 1  
some content  
some more content  
a  
b  
c  

Test 2  
some other content  
some more content  
c  
d  
e  

Test 3....and so on.
```

The part of code I have written is (I have the dictionary in 'xlim' and I have opened the input file in 'f'):

```
g = open('Out.txt','w+')  
for line in f.readlines():  
    p = ''  
    q = ''  
    if "TestCase_2\n" in line:  
        for m in range(len(xlim[1])):  
            p = xlim[1][m]  
            g.write(xlim[1][m])  
            g.write('\n')  
        g.write('\n\n')      
    p,q = q,line   
    g.write(p)  
    g.write(q)  
g.close() ##This writes for the first instance 

#This works for the 2nd instance but stops after that.
g = open('Out.txt')  
h = open('Out1.txt','w+')      
for i in range(2,n+1):  
    g.seek(0)  
    for line in g.readlines():  
        p = ''  
        q = ''  
        if "TestCase_2\n" not in line and 'TestCase_'+str(i+1)+'\n' in line:  
            #print('Yes')  
            for m in range(len(xlim[i])):  
                #p = xlim[i][m]  
                h.write(xlim[i][m])  
                h.write('\n')  
            h.write('\n\n')      

            #print (p)
        p,q = q,line  
        h.write(p)  
        h.write(q)
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have an existing file and I have a dictionary of list. I want to update my file at certain locations(At the end of each "Test X" and before the next "Test Y") with the contents of the dictionary of list. How can i do this?
Apologies if I wasnt clear.

Comment: Usually here on SO you are giving your problem, show the code you already have to solve it and make a clear statement on what is not working as you <re expecting. The "How to…?" type of question is mostly considered to broad.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm posting for the first time so I'm not sure how you are viewing it.But I have shown the code that I wrote and described the problem.

Comment: try using with while handling files like this.
`with open('Out.txt','w+') as f:
        # file read-write code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
import os

append = {'1':['a', 'b', 'c'], '2': ['c', 'd', 'e'], '3': ['g', 'h' , 'i']}

o = open("Out.txt", "w")

flag = False
with open("In.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    o.write(line)
    while line:
        m = re.match("Test (\d)*", line)
        if m:
            flag = True
            test_id = m.group(1)

        line = f.readline()
        if flag:
            if line.strip() == "":
                [o.write(item + os.linesep) for item in append[test_id]]
                flag = False
        o.write(line)

o.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working for the example. I will try it in my code and check!